# joining 2 tables one having multiple rows that matches to first table's row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I came to a situation where I have 2 tables, one has id as PK and another has and another has a timestamp, status, and id as PK. I want to select all the unique rows from table1 when id of table1 matches with an id of table 2.

For example:

Table1

-----id------------timestamp--------------------------status------------col3------

.....111............2017-10-05 10:42:23.................K..........

.....111...............2017-10-05 12:42:23..............X..........

.....111...............2017-10-05 18:42:23..............Y..........

.....222...............2017-10-05 11:42:23..............B..........

Table2

-----id------------col2--------------------------col3------------col4------

.....111...........CCCC............................KKKY..........

.....222............HSGHXF.........................OPUB..........

Here I want to select just 2 unique rows from table1 one having id 111 and another having id 222.

Comment: Note: `id` is not unique (in either table), so it **cannot** be a Primary Key. Please rephrase your question...

Comment: I did. id is PK in the second table.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here but it appears to me that all three rows in table 1 with an id of 111 are unique.  They all have different status and time stamps. You may need to rephrase the question again.

Comment: All the tables in table1 should be unique that is the reason I have id,ts,status as PK. But, I want to select unique rows from table 2 which has same id as table1. Meaning 1 row with 111 id and another row with 222 id

Comment: But there are 3 rows with key = '111' in table1, so you'll have to choose:  **which one** would you like to appear in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> SELECT * FROM table1 AS tbl1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.ID =
>   tbl2.ID

Comment: That will select all 3 rows having id 111. I just want 2 unique rows

Comment: do distinct and inner join

Comment: `group by tbl1.ID` its works to you ? If no, send table details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // I Have two unique rows match and display data in table...   

 <?php
                $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die("not connect".mysql_error());

                    $db=mysql_select_db('persons')or die("could Not connect".mysql_error());




        $res="select persond.personid,orders.OrderNumber,persond.firstname,persond.lastname from persond LEFT JOIN orders ON persond.personid=orders.PersonID" or die("could Not select".mysql_error()); 

        $query=mysql_query($res);

        echo "<table border='1'>";

                        echo "<th>id</th><th>first Name</th><th>lastname</th><th>ordernumber</th>";

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        echo "<tr>";
                        //echo "<td><br/>".$row['id']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['personid']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['OrderNumber']."</td></tr>";
        }

        ?>
```